# RegEx match whole world or starts-with word and/or ends-with another word

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am hoping someone can assist with a RegEx that will match the following:-

- locality
- Locality
- LocalityName
- locality_name
- locality-name
- suburb
- Suburb
- SuburbName
- suburb_name
- suburb-name

But will **NOT** match for:-

- locality_pid
- locality_index
- LocalityRef
- street_locality_pid
- street_suburb_pid

The RegEx I am currently using:-

```
/^(locality|suburb)(?=.*name).*$/img
```

Matches all except the exact words 'locality' and 'suburb'

Comment: `^(locality|suburb)(?:(?:.*)(?:name))*$`

Comment: `^(locality|suburb)(.*name)?$` https://regex101.com/r/ISuWS8/1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
'/^(?:locality|suburb)(?:(?:-|_)?name)?$/im'
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nPPWv4/2)

Sample Code:

```
<?php

$re = '/^(?:locality|suburb)(?:(?:-|_)?name)?$/im';
$str = 'locality
Locality
LocalityName
locality_name
locality-name
suburb
Suburb
SuburbName
suburb_name
suburb-name
locality_pid
locality_index
LocalityRef
street_locality_pid
street_suburb_pid
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);

?>
```

[Run here](http://ideone.com/vuOOyW)

Comment: Thanks Maverick! I can be greedy with the character between 'locality' or 'suburb' and 'name' so have modified as follows:-

     /^(?:locality|suburb)(?:.*name)?$/img